# GetInput() is not defined

Tags: javascript

I want the value from input, when clicked it my function is not defined I can't see the error.

```
function GetInput() {


    var valorinput = document.getElementsByClassName("input_val").value;


    console.log(valorinput);
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Mau5/ubh3Lpaj/7/

Comment: Please don't short circuit adding a fiddle link and no code by placing the link in a code block. That validation is there for a reason ... so you post relevant code in the question itself. Now it's even harder for us, we can't see any code here and we can't even click on a link!

Comment: I fixed it ,is my first ask here.

Comment: This won't work because getElementsByClassName returns list/collection, not single node.

Answer (score -1):

points to note: 
1. js function should be defined well in head as script section.
2. using classname there will be collection of dom elements and for getting the right element need to use index or better to use id attribute.

```
check updated
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ubh3Lpaj/8/)

Comment: Answers should be self contained including the relevant code. Demos should only be used to support what actually exists in the answer itself